# How do you get the "Discriminating Buyer" achievement in CoD MW3

Tags: achievements, call-of-duty-modern-warfare-3

A friend and I are trying to get the "Discriminating Buyer" achievement that is available with the DLC pack that include the "Special Delivery" Spec Op. The achievement text says:

> Use exactly one of each care package in the "Special Deliver" Special Ops mission.

We've run it a few times, and not gotten the achievement. I get that you need one of each package, but two things cause confusion:

1. A "Self Revive" package drops right when the mission starts. Does this package count, or do you need to call in another one?
2. The text says "use" one of each. In order to "use" the self revive, do you just need to call it in and pick it up, or do you actually need to get downed and get up?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was able to get this in a single player Spec Ops game by doing the following:

- Take the Self-Revive at the start of the level
- Call in a care package, which will be a Sentry Gun (you can't decide what the package will contain, unlike in co-op)
- Call in another care package, which will be an Arsenal (ie, an XM-25+Claymores)

There's no need to call in another package.  I *did* call a third one in, which was a sentry gun again, but I did not pick it up. This did not seem to disqualify me.  I assume if I'd already used my Self Revive by this point, I'd end up getting another.

I will also add that I ended up using my self-revive, but never called in another.  Judging by the comments, this seems to be important.  I also did *not* have to fire the XM-25 or set any of the claymores from the Arsenal package.

Comment: Uggh... still didn't work for me.  Took self revive, and sentry, and arsenal.  Used arsenal but dropped it.  Carried sentry to end.  Did not get downed.  Sigh.

Comment: @EBongo - I did get downed near the end.  Maybe you actually have to use it?

Answer (score 1):

I also got this achievement by doing the following.

1. Take the self-revive package at the start of the level.
2. Call in a care package, it will be a sentry gun.  set it up, make sure it gets a kill
3. Call in the next care package, the Arsenal, make sure you get a kill with it
4. Try to hold off on getting downed until you get the second intel package.  kill the two    jugs in the warehouse, then let a chump down you.  at that point you use the self-revive package.
5. Beat the rest of the mission without calling in more care packages or dying (obviously).

Answer (score 0):

I downed myself with a grenade at the end of the level after killing all the enemies and then used the Self Revive ;)